# Display link in UserForm with Friendly_Name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `UserForm` and use the following VBA to have the `Label` as a link:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

In `Cell A1` in my Excel-Sheet I have written `www.stackoverflow.com`.

---

The link functionality itself works perfectly.

However, the label in the userform displays the full link `www.stackoverflow.com`. 
I would prefer if it uses a `friendly_name` like just `stackoverflow`. 
The same way it is done in the `HYERPLINK` formula in Excel.

How can I achieve this in a VBA-Userform?

Comment: Is the label.. dynamic? Why can't you just do `Label1_Caption = "stackoverflow"`? Or can you have the friendly name in cell `B1` and `Label1_Caption = Sheet1.Range("B1").Value`?

Comment: Thanks. That is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is as described in the comments by Raymon Wu:

**Excel Sheet**

```
  |               A           |        B          |      C
--|---------------------------|-------------------|----------------
1 |  www.stackoverflow.com    |   stackoverflow   |
2 |                           |                   |
3 |                           |                   |
```

**VBA**

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()
Label1.Caption = Sheet1.Range("B1").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the labels `Tag` property to hold the link, while the `Caption` property holds the friendly name.

So your form holds this code:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Label1.Tag
End Sub
```

An a normal module holds this code:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MyForm As UserForm1
    Set MyForm = New UserForm1
    
    With MyForm
        .Label1.Tag = Sheet1.Range("A1")
        .Label1.Caption = Sheet1.Range("B1")
        .Show
    End With

End Sub
```